# How to use dataframe defined in one buttons observeevent inside another button's observeevent?

Tags: r, shiny

This is the code:

button 1 is an `actionbutton` ,the `observeevent` is defined as follows

```
 observeEvent(
    input$button1,{


   mid<-c("1","2")

   name<-c("a","b")

  datatable1<-data.frame(mid,name)

output$deatilscv <- renderUI({

 div(id="div1",

          fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

   actionButton("button2", "CLICK")  )) )}


observeEvent(

    input$button2,{

a<-datatable1(1,1)  #this shows an error datatable1 not found

print(a)
})
```

How to access `datatable1` details inside `observeevent` of `actionbutton button2`

Comment: U need to look at `eventReactive`

Comment: I have used eventReactive instead of the observeEvent of the button 2 but it doesnot displays anything

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Example"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("button1", "button1")
        ),
        mainPanel(
           uiOutput("deatilscv")
        )
      )
    ))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      datatable1 <- eventReactive(input$button1, {
              mid<-c("1","2")
              name<-c("a","b")
              tmp <- data.frame(mid,name)
      })
      output$deatilscv <- renderUI({
              if(!input$button1) return()
              div(id="div1",

                  fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

                            actionButton("button2", "CLICK")  ))
      })
      observeEvent(

              input$button2,{

                      a <- datatable1()[1,1]  #this shows an error datatable1 not found

                      print(a)
              })  
    })
```

note that the print(a) in the observe event prints to the console.

Comment: How can this be done for actionButton  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034088/how-to-access-dataframe-from-another-observeevent?noredirect=1#comment65418706_39034088

Comment: You have edited your coment so I am not sure if you are still interested in the radio buttons version. If yes take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons version

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Example"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
                radioButtons("rb1", "Select options", choices = c("Choice1", "Choice2"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
           uiOutput("deatilscv1"),
           uiOutput("deatilscv2")
        )
      )
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      datatable1 <- eventReactive(input$rb1, {

              if (input$rb1 == "Choice1") {
                      mid<-c("1","2")
                      name<-c("a","b")
                      tmp <- data.frame(mid,name)                         
              } else {
              mid<-c("3","4")
              name<-c("c","d")
              tmp <- data.frame(mid,name)
              }
              tmp
      })
      output$deatilscv1 <- renderUI({
              if(input$rb1 != "Choice1") return()
              div(id="div1",

                  fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

                            actionButton("button2", "CLICK1"),
                            renderDataTable(DT::datatable(datatable1()))))
      })
      output$deatilscv2 <- renderUI({
              if(input$rb1 !="Choice2") return()
              div(id="div1",

                  fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

                            actionButton("button3", "CLICK2"),
                            renderDataTable(DT::datatable(datatable1()))))
      })
      observeEvent(

              input$button2,{

                      a <- datatable1()[1,1]  #this shows an error datatable1 not found

                      print(a)
              })  
      observeEvent(

              input$button3,{

                      a <- datatable1()[1,1]  #this shows an error datatable1 not found

                      print(a)
              }) 
    })
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked.Sir is there any way to display the dataframe tmp using datatbleoutput function.I used it inside div1 but it didnt worked.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include datatables rendering. This should get you started.